# weather_forecast_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_weather_forecast) NameError: name 'threading' is not define

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import os
import requests
import json
import time
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6136345650:AAGfx6__KX1Hb3h9QV3tLEnHIcGbEI9JK4k')

# создаем базу данных для хранения геопозиций пользователей
conn = sqlite3.connect('user_locations.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_locations
                (user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, latitude REAL, longitude REAL)''')
conn.commit()

# функция для получения прогноза погоды по координатам
def get_weather(lat, lon):
    api_key = '39e6bbf429e800651c6c2d41b76d09c0'
    url = f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={api_key}&units=metric'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = json.loads(response.content)
        weather = data['weather'][0]['description']
        temp = data['main']['temp']
        return f'Погода сейчас: {weather}, температура: {temp}°C'
    else:
        return 'Не удалось получить прогноз погоды'

# функция для отправки прогноза погоды каждые 2 часа
def send_weather_forecast():
    while True:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user_locations')
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            user_id = row[0]
            lat = row[1]
            lon = row[2]
            weather_forecast = get_weather(lat, lon)
            bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=weather_forecast)
        time.sleep(7200) # ждем 2 часа

# обработчик команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='Привет! Отправь мне свою геопозицию, чтобы получать прогноз погоды каждые 2 часа')

# обработчик геопозиции
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['location'])
def location_message(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    lat = message.location.latitude
    lon = message.location.longitude
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO user_locations (user_id, latitude, longitude) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_id, lat, lon))
    conn.commit()
    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='Спасибо! Теперь вы будете получать прогноз погоды каждые 2 часа')

запускаем поток для отправки прогноза погоды каждые 2 часа
weather_forecast_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_weather_forecast)
weather_forecast_thread.start()
# обработчик геопозиции
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['location'])
def location_message(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    lat = message.location.latitude
    lon = message.location.longitude
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO user_locations (user_id, latitude, longitude) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_id, lat, lon))
    conn.commit()
    bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='Спасибо! Теперь вы будете получать прогноз погоды каждые 2 часа')
    
    # отправляем информацию админу
    admin_chat_id = 'ADMIN_CHAT_ID'
    admin_username = message.chat.username
    location_info = f'Пользователь {admin_username} ({user_id}) отправил геопозицию: широта - {lat}, долгота - {lon}'
    bot.send_message(chat_id=admin_chat_id, text=location_info)
```

Выдает ошибку :

> weather_forecast_thread =
> threading.Thread(target=send_weather_forecast) NameError: name
> 'threading' is not define

Comment: Ну, видимо, `import threading` надо сделать предварительно.

Comment: @CrazyElf   File "C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\bot\pogoda.py", line 34, in send_weather_forecast
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user_locations')
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 8924 and this is thread id 2452.

Comment: @CrazyElf File "C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\bot\pogoda.py", line 34, in send_weather_forecast
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM user_locations')
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 8924 and this is thread id 2452.

Comment: @ИванСиропов, все дополнения вносите в сам вопрос, чтобы отредактровать вопрос - нажмите [edit] под ним. В текущем виде проблема озвученная в вопросе решается добавление импорта. Если возникла другая проблема, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите ее.